# Thunderbird: disable ENTER opening all messages in thread

Tags: email, thunderbird

When using thread view in Thunderbird, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on collapsed thread does not un-collapse the thread as would be logical, but instead opens all emails in that thread in separate windows.

Is there a way to change this unfortunate behavior, and instead un-collapse the thread when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

I am using Thunderbird (Icedove) 24.8.1 on Debian.

Comment: Aside: I assume pressing Space expands/un-collapses the list?  If there's not a workaround, remembering the supported shortcut might help avoid pressing the "wrong" one.

Comment: I'd rather search at Mozilla Thunderbird support/community https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/get-community-support

Comment: I had no luck at the [Mozilla Thunderbird support/community](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1083932#answer-782089) so I am coming back here to start a bounty

Comment: What DE or WM are using? Would a WM-specific solution be acceptable?

Comment: @A.P. -  I am not sure how WM-specific solution would work

Comment: @MartinVegter Not sure myself yet, but part of the solution could be some GUI scripting when TB window has focus. Focused window detection could be WM-specific.

Comment: @A.P. - that sounds terribly complicated

Comment: @MartinVegter I wouldn't say "terribly", but I see what you mean. On the other hand, I don't think an easy solution exists to your problem, apart from a kludge of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You may press <kbd>Right</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> to uncollapse the thread.
- You may set "operate_on_msgs_in_collapsed_threads" to false in config editor (as indicated in your [Mozilla support issue](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1083932#answer-782089).) so that only the current mail opens on <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- You may install [Dorando Keyconfig extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dorando-keyconfig/) and setup up a command to archive whole conversation (as not indicated in your Mozilla support issue). Just assign these two commands to a key of your choice.

`goDoCommand('cmd_selectThread');
goDoCommand('cmd_archive');`

That way, while reading a single mail, you may get rid of the whole thread at once, not delete 70 e-mails individually.
(Me, personally, I am very happy with this solution. It allows me not to use the Thunderbird conversation extension that brings some GMail like funcionality to Thunderbird, but brings many integration issues.)